# Add & Remove Class With jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently trying to add and remove a class using jQuery on a UL immediately after an a tag (on click of the a tag) but can't get it to work for some reason. Any help would be appreciated, thanks. Code snippets below:

```
$(document).on("click", "a.navDropTrigger", function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass("navDropHover")) {
        $this.closest(".navDrop").removeClass("navDropHover");  
    } 
    else {
        $this.next(".navDrop").addClass("navDropHover");
    }
});

<li><a class="navDropTrigger" href="#">Work</a>
    <ul class="navDrop">
    <li><a href="/work.php">Project Name</a></li>
    <li><a href="/work.php">Project Name</a></li>
    <li><a href="/work.php">Project Name Long</a></li>
    <li><a href="/work.php">Project Name This One Too</a></li>
    <li><a href="/work.php">Project Name</a></li>
    <li><a href="/work.php">Project Name</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: replace `$this.closest(".navDrop").removeClass("navDropHover");` with `$this.siblings(".navDrop").removeClass("navDropHover");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is that you are searching from `document` instead of the link that was clicked on.

Replace:

```
 var $this = $(this);
```

with

```
var $this = $(e.target);
```

You'll also need to capture the event object for this to work.

Add a `e` argument to the anonymous event handler function like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "a.navDropTrigger", function(e){
```

Then you will be working from the link that was clicked instead of the whole document.

This is important because since while you having shown multiple menus in this example you:

- Open the HTML with `<li>` indicating this this is one of several similar things in a list
- Are trying to search relative to something
- Using classes instead of IDs

---

You are trying to use `closest`. See the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/closest/):

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

The list is the next sibling of the link, not an ancestor of it. (It isn't an ancestor of the `document` object you were searching from either).

Use [`next`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) instead.

You also need to use it **consistently**. You have to test for the presence of the class on the same element that you add and remove the class from.

---

```js
$(document).on("click", "a.navDropTrigger", function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.next(".navDrop").hasClass("navDropHover")) {
    $this.next(".navDrop").removeClass("navDropHover");
  } else {
    $this.next(".navDrop").addClass("navDropHover");
  }
});
```

```css
.navDrop {
  display: none;
}

.navDropHover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a class="navDropTrigger" href="#">Work</a>
    <ul class="navDrop">
      <li><a href="/work.php">Project Name</a></li>
      <li><a href="/work.php">Project Name</a></li>
      <li><a href="/work.php">Project Name Long</a></li>
      <li><a href="/work.php">Project Name This One Too</a></li>
      <li><a href="/work.php">Project Name</a></li>
      <li><a href="/work.php">Project Name</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a class="navDropTrigger" href="#">Play</a>
    <ul class="navDrop">
      <li><a href="/work.php">Project Name</a></li>
      <li><a href="/work.php">Project Name</a></li>
      <li><a href="/work.php">Project Name Long</a></li>
      <li><a href="/work.php">Project Name This One Too</a></li>
      <li><a href="/work.php">Project Name</a></li>
      <li><a href="/work.php">Project Name</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: OP needs to traverse down the DOM tree. He needs .find().

Comment: @symlink — No, they don't. See the first half of this answer.

Comment: .navDrop is a child of .navDropTrigger. If it wasn't, my jsFiddle wouldn't work. You're overthinking this, dude.

Comment: @symlink — It isn't. It is a sibling: `<a class="navDropTrigger" href="#">Work</a><ul class="navDrop">`. The end tag for `navDropTrigger` is immediately before the start tag for `navDrop`. Your code works because you are searching *the whole document* (**and** you only have one dropdown in it) that is why the first thing my answer does is to change `var $this` so that it isn't the whole document.

Comment: You are actually right, but you came at me half cocked, and my answer worked, so, whatever, your message was confusing. I upvoted your answer, and fixed mine. Feel free to use my jsFiddle if you want.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are searching for and checking on the right element:

```
$(document).click(".navDropTrigger", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(e.target).next(".navDrop").hasClass("navDropHover")) {
        $(e.target).next(".navDrop").removeClass("navDropHover");
    } else {
        $(e.target).next(".navDrop").addClass("navDropHover");
    }  
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3apb6qcq/1/

Comment: You seem to be recommending that they change the selector from `a.navDropTrigger` to `.navDropTrigger`. How would that help? We can see the HTML. The only element that is a member of that class is an `a`.

Comment: @Quentin it's just a style preference of mine. Doesn't affect the code one way or another.

Comment: Correction: It's searching from `document`, so it is a descendant … but you're finding **every* `navDrop` and not just the one near the link being toggled. (To be fair, the example in the question doesn't show multiple menus, but it is a reasonable assumption that there will be).

Comment: I'm not attacking you. I'm criticising your answer, and I'm doing that because it has significant drawbacks which will cause it to break if there is more than one dropdown menu. https://jsfiddle.net/3apb6qcq/2/